# How to set a different versionCode for a Google Instant App which uses the same single module as the installable version?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I am trying to create an instant Android app for a small app with just one module. I have added
`<dist:module dist:instant="true" />`
to the manifest and can now start the app as regular app and as instant app from Android Studio in the emulator. Both versions are basically the same, except for some places where I use `isInstantApp()` to check if the app is running in instant or regular/installable app. So all seems to be working fine.

However for uploading the app to the Google PlayStore I need a different versionCode for the instant and for the installable app.

I am puzzled how to do this as basically the generated apk seems to be the same.

I have tried using flavorDimensions in build.gradle, but this way I have to create two different app bundles, one for instant and one for the installable app.